# Redirect with htaccess; 404 error without backslash

Tags: .htaccess

I have a page on my website;

`page.php` and I want it to accessible through `example.com/folder/page/`. I use the following  htaccess code for that:

```
RewriteRule ^page$ page.php [NC,L] #remove .php
RewriteRule ^folder/page/$ http://www.example.com/page
```

And this works. If I navigate to `example.com/folder/page/` I get shown the right page. The problem is, when I visit `example.com/folder/page` (no `/`) I get a 404 error. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the slash optional by adding **?** in your regex

```
RewriteRule ^folder/page/?$ http://www.example.com/page
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know it was so easy.